# Is there any difference in these two React small components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider these two components:

```
function App1 () {
    return <button onClick={() => null}>Click me</button>
}
```

```
function App2 () {
    const fn = () => null;
    return <button onClick={fn}>Click me</button>
}
```

Only difference is the click handler is defined inline in the first case, and extracted in a function in the latter.

I've always thought these snippets behave exaclty the same way.
The only way I could imagine this not being the case is if JSX transpilation alters the outputs, [but it doesn't seem the case](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.21&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQQA6oIyIBQEpEDeAUAJABOAplCGUgDwBGIUUCiCAwgDYwQDWAXgJ5EAgHyIwILlwC-Y7rz6IAthToB6JiwRiisokVCRYbNKgBMOfMUSISEBAGcoiYEgHXREqTIDcpJTUtIiMzKxInDz8Qu7yivyq6lrhuvpAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&modules=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.23.10&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)

Today I've been told that in `App1` the inline function is created every time the component re-renders, but this doesn't happen in `App2`. This also obtained initial confirmation by ChatGPT:

```
[ChatGPT]
In App1, the arrow function is directly declared inside the onClick attribute. 
This means that a new function instance is created each time the component re-renders.

In App2, the arrow function fn is declared outside of the render function and then passed as a reference to the onClick attribute. 
This means that the same function instance is used across re-renders.
```

But this seems wrong: it seems ChatGPT consider only the JSX section being part of the render function, but **App2 is the render function**, and is re-executed in its interety every time there's a re-render, so recreating each time also `fn`.
When I pointed this out with ChatGPT, it apologized (of course), and changed its version.

So I'm asking this here: **Is any difference in these two components?**

Comment: 1. JSX is not natively supported by most JS runtimes (including at the time I write this node.js and every browser). So it has to be compiled to something that is. You would have to look at the compiled output to see if there's any actual difference, and there isn't. 2. Javascript itself is not natively executed by any hardware I'm aware of. It has to be compiled into something that is. Most JS runtimes will JIT compile the code. Given the number of times React re-renders it is totally possible that even if there was a difference in them at *build* time it would be compiled away at *runtime*.

Comment: Yes, there's no difference in the compiled JSX for it... There's also a link in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Never trust a robot to do a programmer's job. :snort:

The lambda is created anew on each render in both cases.  To avoid the lambda being re-created it would need to be wrapped in something like `useMemo` or moved outside of the component.

i.e. they are the same

Comment: That's what I also always thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only declare your function once, you must put it outside the component

```
const fn = () => null;

function App () {    
  return <button onClick={fn}>Click me</button>
}
```

If you want to cache function definitions between re-renders, make sure to wrap it in a `useCallback` hook

```
function App () {    
  const fn = useCallback(() => null, []);

  return <button onClick={fn}>Click me</button>
}
```

Reference: https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback

Comment: Already know these things... and this is not what I was asking. The question is: are you aware of any difference between App1 and App2. I've always thought they are perfectly equivalent.